# Не могу склонировать репозиторий с Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]выдает следующее
`remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied`
`fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bmstu.codes/a.tymina/first_project.git/`
В интернетах писали что нужно зайти в диспетчер учетных данных -> учетные данные Widows
далее найти то что связано с гитом и поменять пароль или что-то в этом роде , но у меня нет там гита

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Если авторизация через https, то по идее  нужно ввести те данные (логин, пароль), под которыми заходите на гитлаб.

Answer (score 0):

Написано же — простая авторизация запрещена. Скорее всего вам нужно создать [персональный токен](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#create-a-personal-access-token) и вводить его вместо пароля.

Comment: В ошибке не написано, что простая авторизация запрещена, написано только что не удалось аутентифицироваться.

Comment: HTTP **Basic** — простая. Разве нет?

Comment: @Александр-Тымин В диспетчере учетных данных надо искать не гит, а тот сервер, с которым проблема. Это `https://bmstu.codes`

Comment: `echo "url=https://bmstu.codes" | git credential reject`
такая команда наверное обнулит авторизацию